# Stripe client_secret, my react app not getting it

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase, express

```
my backend code...
app.post('/payments/create', async (req, res) => {
        const total = req.query.total;
    
        console.log('Payment Request Received', total);
    
        const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
            amount: total,
            currency: 'usd'
        })
    
        res.status(201).send({
            clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret,
        })
    })
```

my frontend code

```
const [clientSecret, setClientSecret] = useState(true);
```

That's my state...

```
useEffect(() => {
        const getClientSecret = async () => {
            const response = await axios({
                method: 'post',
                url: `/payments/create?total=${getBasketTotal(basket) * 100}`
            });
            setClientSecret(response.data.clientSecret);
        }
        getClientSecret();
    }, [basket]);
```

Then that's my useEffect that's supposed to fetch me the clientSecret... But I keep getting the initial state of (true) everytime the basket instance updates...

Please help me... what can be done? It seems my state is not updating, or I am not getting the clientSecret... I don't know which is really happening.

Comment: For some reason its not running your useeffect. Can you log inside `useEffect` . Is it going there or not?

Comment: Can you let us know if the request is being sent or not?

Comment: if `basket` is a nested object, there is a good possibility that the `shallow` comparison on `basket` changes are not triggering the `useEffect`. Can you please try the logging inside `useEffect`, as @ShubhamVerma suggested.

Comment: sorry for the late reply please... But i tried logging it inside my useEffect, it's still returning "true"

Comment: Is there a way to send an image file here please? I need to share the screenshot here..